# C# Thread example code working without a lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having a play with Threads to remind myself how they work, I haven't done any Threading code in ages.

So I thought I'd start with the most basic example, create n threads, get them updating a static int without a lock, so I can see it go wrong. However, it's working? The final value is 500 every time, it should be slightly random as Threads update the value at the same time

I know I'm doing something really stupid here but I can't see what

https://dotnetfiddle.net/w9TK5W

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class Department
    {
        public static int a = 0;

        public Department()
        {            
        }

        public void Inc()
        {
            a = a +5;
            a = a -4;
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        int count = 500;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[count];
        Department dep = new Department();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(dep.Inc));
            threads[i] = t;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Start();                
        }

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Join();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Department.a.ToString());
    }
}
```

[Edit, more info]

So I changed the loop to look like this, it now works as expected

```
      int b = a;
        
        b = b+1;
        
        int j=0;
        for (int i=0; i<1E5; i++)
        {
            j += i;
        }
        
        a = b;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computation in each thread is so short that probably each started thread is already ended before the next one actually starts.
This happens just *by chance*.
You should run in each thread a loop that performs millions of operations on `a`, and then you will probably detect the expected inconsistency.

The question has been edited with millions of operation which do not alter `a`, thus *by chance* again, the very few operations that actually alter `a` don't happen at the same time.

The question has been edited since the previous remark, but now it fails for a different reason than the expected initial one.
Reading `a`, waiting a bit, and altering `a` based on the read value is obviously not atomic.
If the loop simply performed `a+=1`, you could also see that this apparently trivial operation is not atomic either.